# Update Panel in ContentPage button Click not updating repeater in MasterPage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, master-pages, content-pages

I have an update panel inside contentpage when I click the button in there, I'm checking on breakpoint running this code block but its not refresing the masterpages controls. still empty repeater and also label. After that I try f5 on browser then updating.

```
 var master = Master as mpage;
        if (master != null)
        {
            master.function();  // here the function databinding repeater inside masterpage
            var rp= (Repeater)Master.FindControl("repeaterInMasterPage");
             
            rp.DataBind();
        }
```

but not refreshing the repeater in masterpage and also label control in masterpage.

Best Regards

Comment: is there anybody to answer that problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem via trying alternative ways.

Just need to put the controls in an `UpdatePanel` on masterpage. And call update function of the `UpdatePanel` in content page codebehind.